# Angular material toolbar not inheriting from angular materials

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

I want to integrate a nav bar on the left side of my application. But the inheriting in css seems not to work.

the nav toolbar should inherit like in the video the style from angular material "IF" I got it right. Right now there is basically nothing inherited. I have no errors in the console and im sure, I have imported roboto etc.

I'm guided with a youtube video since I'm new in this field:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6qhzG7mObU
I updated my npm and ng. Furthermore I used 'ng add @angular/material' for making sure everything is configured and imported correctly.

app.module.ts:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MainNavComponent } from './main-nav/main-nav.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainNavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

styles.css:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
```

this is the auto generated template for a material toolbar
main-nav-component.ts:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true"
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>XML-ConfiguratorV2</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

and here the css with the problem:

```
.sidenav .mat-toolbar {
  background: inherit;
}
```

Now the result I actually get is this:
[image: actual]
[image: expected]

Thanks for help :D

Comment: Have you tried to include one of the standard themes as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)? Just add `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` at the top of your `styles.css`.

Comment: Screenshots are working on my end. I did that with 'ng add'. The style is working for the application, but inheriting the style for mat-sidenav doesn't seem to work. [link](https://imgur.com/a/BW70E2C) "screenshots"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `color="primary"` in `mat-toolbar` of `mat-sidenav`. So, in your code :

```html
...
<mat-sidenav-container ...>
    <mat-sidenav ...>
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar> // Note : color="primary" at this line
    </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, worked. I also had to delete the background: inherit style from .sidenav and .mat-toolbar. Now it looks like I expect it to be. Don't know why the auto-generated template is broken ^^'...

Comment: I had the same problem!
Thank you all for your comments!